# Replace each occurrence in yaml from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, yaml

I have a yaml file which has the structure:

```
data:
 - sets:
 - header: null
    params:
    - {name:id, value:'123'}
    - {name:id2, value:'234'}
 - header: null
    params:
    - {name:id3, value:'567'}
    - {name:id5, value:'456'}
```

I need to replace each occurrence of `"- header: null"` with

```
- header:
  - {name:id, value:'<value from csv>'}
```

by iterating through the csv file. There are the same number of rows in the csv file as there are number of occurrences in the yaml file.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I tried using regular expression but that was not successful.

Comment: Your YAML is invalid due to the indentation of `params:` (needs to be on the same level as `header:`). Also have you considered using a YAML implementation and a CSV implementation instead of regexes?

Comment: sorry this is just a snapshot of the yaml file but I just need to replace each occurrence with an entry from the csv file. I did look at those implementations but I'm unsure as to how to iterate through both the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used

```
for dataSet, row in zip(dataSets, csv):
        dataSet['authHeaders'] = [dict(name='value', value=row[0]), dict(name='value2', value='abc')]
```